# Predictive analysis based on history

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

Let me first say that I am a CS person and my knowledge about statistics is quite basic. I am trying to see what predictive analysis to use for a problem I am trying to solve. I will try to make my problem general also so that anyone can benefit from the question. Basically, I have a group of objects that I am watching over a certain period of time. By the end of that period, some objects remain unchanged, other objects are modified by a small amount, while other ones change completely. I am trying to look at a small history of these objects and predict how they will change in the future. I want to identify what are the parameters that affect their future behavior and how they affect their future behavior. I dont know what part of statistics should I look into. I think it is important to say that the outcome is discrete. I want to classify those objects into "stable", "change by a small value", or completely change.

This is my problem specifically. Instead of objects, I actually have memory pages. Each memory page is 4024 bytes. In a period of five minutes, some of these pages will change completely. Others will stay the same. Others will change by a little bit. I want to classify pages into three categories. I have a second by second data of the whole memory for the whole five minutes. So I do know how the pages will change. I was wondering if I can look into a shorter amount of time. Lets say three seconds and be able to predict what category this page will fall into.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question- it seems that the answer could be immensely general. Are you looking for correlations? You might want to look into "covariance" and see where that takes you. Be sure to also look into regression (linear, logarithmic, etc): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_analytics#Regression_techniques

Comment: This is my problem. Instead of objects, I actually have memory pages. Each memory page is 4024 bytes. In a period of five minutes, some of these pages will change completely. Others will stay the same. Others will change by a little bit. I want to classify pages into three categories. I have a second by second data of the whole memory for the whole five minutes. So I do know how the pages will change. I was wondering if I can look into a shorter amount of time. Lets say three seconds and be able to predict what category this page will fall into.

Comment: ^^ You should add that to your question- it's valuable context.